# Global model in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'd like to add map as attribute to spring's servlet and get its values like attributes in request or session model (${map['key']}). How can I add this map?

Found one method as interceptor. Are there another solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interceptors are the appropriate and intended way to pre-process requests and apply logic globally. They are analogous with filters in a pure servlet environment and should be thought of in the same way.

Create your own interceptor and decorate or add attributes to you request in there.

Comment: OK. I used it and got satisfied. Thanks for explaining.